# ¿Como cerrar un formulario y abrir otro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo diseñados tres formularios, uno es para iniciar sesión, el otro para registrarse y el tercero es el formulario principal al cual tienen acceso una vez iniciado sesión o al registrarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en las imágenes, en cada formulario existe un botón para invocar a otros formularios, por ejemplo el formulario Iniciar Sesión tiene un botón que llama al formulario para registrarse, y el formulario Registrarse también tiene un botón que llama la formulario para iniciar sesión, es decir, ambos formularios deben intercalarse de acuerdo al botón que se presione. El sistema arranca con el formulario Iniciar Sesión y cuando presiono el botón Registrarse este muestra el formulario para registrarse, pero lo muestra encima del formulario Iniciar Sesión, averiguando un poco decían que hay que ocultar el formulario para que parezca que el formulario invocado esta solo, pero el problema de esto es que si cierro el formulario invocado el programa todavía sigue corriendo pero sin embargo ya no hay mas formularios a la vista. Otro problema que también note es de que el programa finaliza solo cuando cierro el formulario con el que empezó, en este caso yo deseo que el programa finalice cuando cierre la ventana de iniciar sesión o registrarse.

Una vez que se haya iniciado sesión o registrado, estos formularios deben cerrarse e invocar al tercer formulario que es el principal donde se hacen todas las operaciones y si yo cierro el tercer formulario automáticamente debe finalizar la ejecución del programa y no esperar que cierre el formulario de Iniciar Sesión con el que empezó a correr el sistema. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Espero haber entendido bien tu quieres que se oculte el anterior form, bueno puedes usar la funcion hide

en el boton donde mandas llamar al otro formulario agregas la función hide

This.Hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que finaliza la ejecucion cuando cierras el form de inicio de sesion se produce porque define este como inicio de la aplicacion en el `Aplication.Run()` y eso esta mal

[[Winform] Realizar tareas antes de inicializar aplicación](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-winforms-realizar-tareas-antes-de.html)

en el articulo lo explico, pero veras que uso

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    //
    // Realizo la apertura del formulario para validar el login
    // esta tarea es previa al inicio de la aplicacion
    //
    frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
    login.ShowDialog();

    //
    // Si el login es correcto, procedo con la apetura normal
    // de la aplicacion
    //
    if (login.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        Application.Run(new frmPrincipal());

}
```

la idea es que la autenticacion se realice en el `Main()` de `Program.cs` previo a definir el `Aplication.Run()`

Respecto al form de registracion no habria problemas en mostrarlo por sobre el de autenticacion siempre que lo realices de forma modal, para eso usa el `ShowDialog()` para mostrarlo